# Failed to parse JSON using Biquery from Google storage bucket

Tags: json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I upload from my backend the attached JSON to Google bucket,
Now I'm trying to connect this JSON to the Bigquery table but getting the following error, what are the changes I need to make?

> Error while reading table: XXXXX, error message: Failed to parse JSON: No object found when new array is started.; BeginArray returned false; Parser terminated before end of string

[image]

```
[["video_screen","click_on_screen","false","202011231958","1","43","0"],["buy","error","2","202011231807","1","6","0"],["sign_in","enter","user_details","202011231220","2","4","0"],["video_screen","click_on_screen","false","202011230213","1","4","0"],["video_screen","click_on_screen","false","202011230633","1","4","0"],["video_screen","click_on_screen","false","202011230709","1","4","0"],["video_screen","click_on_screen","false","202011230712","1","4","0"],["video_screen","click_on_screen","false","202011230723","1","4","0"],["video_screen","click_on_screen","false","202011230725","1","4","0"],["video_screen","click_on_screen","false","202011231739","1","4","0"],["category","select","MTV","202011232228","1","3","0"],["sign_in","enter","user_details","202011230108","2","3","0"],["sign_in","enter","user_details","202011230442","2","3","0"],["video","select","youtube","202011230108","1","3","0"],["video","select","youtube","202011230633","1","3","0"],["video_screen","click_on_screen","false","202011230458","1","3","0"],["video_screen","click_on_screen","false","202011230552","1","3","0"],["video_screen","click_on_screen","false","202011230612","1","3","0"],["video_screen","click_on_screen","false","202011231740","1","3","0"],["category","select","Disney Karaoke","202011232228","1","2","0"],["category","select","Duet","202011232228","1","2","0"],["category","select","Free","202011230726","1","2","0"],["category","select","Free","202011231830","2","2","0"],["category","select","Free","202011232228","1","2","0"],["category","select","Love","202011232228","1","2","0"],["category","select","New","202011232228","1","2","0"],["category","select","Pitch Perfect 2","202011232228","1","2","0"],["developer","click","hithub","202011230749","1","2","0"],["sign_in","enter","user_details","202011230134","1","2","0"],["sign_in","enter","user_details","202011230211","1","2","0"],["sign_in","enter","user_details","202011230219","1","2","0"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Bigquery reads [JSONL](https://jsonlines.org/) files.  The example is *not* in that format.

1. JSONL uses `\n` as the delimeter between records.  The example is all on one line with commas delimiting.
2. Every JSONL line is a json object, so starts with `{` and ends with `}`. The example has JSON arrays which are not supported.
3. JSONL is based on [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).  Every data element needs to be named. So the first record might appear as `{ "field1_name": "video_screen", "field2_name": "click_on_screen", "field3_name": false, "field4_name": 202011231958, "Field5_name": 1, "field6_name": 43, "field7_name": 0}`
4. JSONL does not have the outer pair of brackets `[]`. The first line starts `{` not `[{` and the last line ends `}` not `}]`.

Comment: OK, so do you have a clue how to insert this data to bigquery from the bigbucket ?

Comment: @idan the file is going to have to opened by something other than bigquery.  You could rewrite the file in a format that bigquery understands, or you could open the file and use a bigquery API in your programming language to write directly to bigquery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python solution for what Steven has answered in order to convert a JSON file in GCS to something BigQuery can import. *bucket, gcp_prefix, source_file* and *modified_name* are variables relevant to your GCS project and you will not need gcp_prefix if the file is in the bucket root:

```
import json

from google.cloud import storage
from io import BytesIO, StringIO


def get_gcs_bucket(bucket_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    return bucket


def download_from_gcs(bucket_name, file_name):
    file_io = BytesIO()
    bucket = get_gcs_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
    blob.download_to_file(file_io)

    return file_io


def upload_to_gcs(bucket_name, file_name, file_io):
    bucket = get_gcs_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
    blob.upload_from_file(file_io, rewind=True)
    blob_id = f'gs://{blob.id}'

    return blob_id


def generate_json_file(gcs_object):
    gcs_object.seek(0)
    decoded_json = json.loads(gcs_object.read().decode('utf-8'))
    content_string = [json.dumps(row) for row in decoded_json]
    json_content = '\n'.join(content_string)

    return json_content


file_object = BytesIO(download_from_gcs(bucket, source_file)['Body'].read())
modified_json = generate_json_file(file_object)
binary_json = StringIO(modified_json).getvalue().encode('utf-8')
blob_id = upload_to_gcs(bucket, f'{gcp_prefix}/{modified_name}', binary_json)
```